# How do I subtract 1 from a cell's value if another cell contains a specific word?

Tags: google-sheets

How do I subtract the amount of 1 from cell B2 if the word "text" is written into cell A1?

Comment: This is not a question. We welcome your contributions to Web Applications but a question should identify a problem that needs to be solved.  Please be sure to take the [Tour] and also review [ask]. If you have a problem that hasn't already been asked in the past and have found a solution, you can post a question and self-answer it.  Please be sure to first search the existing [tag:google-sheets] questions on this site for duplicates.  We encourage you to familiarize yourself with how the site works and look forward to your future contributions!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because elementary information like this is best provided by the official [function list](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273) and the [Learning Center](https://support.google.com/a/users/answer/9282959).

Comment: If you have a question about a function or formula please include it and what is or is not working, including any error messages you may have encountered.

Comment: @doubleunary I disagree as  what constitutes elementary is a relative opinion. This is a application of `IF` formula, just like any other formula application. OP wants to contribute to the community, which is a good thing. We should always encourage contributions no matter how small they may seem to our expert eyes and not belittle it, IMHO.

Comment: @TheMaster Fair enough. Meta consensus indeed was that lack of research is not a valid close reason. But I am of the opinion that OPs who ask questions like "how do I add two numbers together" would be best served by existing vendor resources rather than WebApps. Tag info for [tag:google-sheets] tells _"Before posting a question: Check the [Official Documentation](http://support.google.com/docs) and make use of Sheet's inbuilt Help, in particular for the syntax required by [functions](https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?visit_id=1-636459177854577018-232500333&hl=en&rd=2)."_

Comment: @TheMaster The contribution serves them and the community if they have the opportunity to learn something from it.  You pre-empted that opportunity. If you care about them you will support them, teach them, and provide feedback to them. If you care about the community you will support existing contributors as well as new.

Comment: @Blindspots They did learn something new, they enjoyed it so much and wanted to share it to the next guy. We should encourage the joy of learning and joy of sharing. We  shouldn't unnecessarily bog them with rules. When we do things like that, we show ourselves friendly. When they learn something new, they'll be happy to share it to us again. I'm more concerned with users who bring nothing but questions and asking "give me give me give me teh codez" and users who answer with nothing but the codes-which nearly profit no one except the OP. It's the heart that matters. Spirit above the letter.

Answer (score 1):

```
=IF(A1="text";B2-1;B2)
```

This will subtract 1 from cell B2 if the word "text" is in cell A1.